# ansible execute a single module on a single host

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I would like to do something like this :

```
ansible -i MYHOST, windows -m win_ping
```

I have `MYHOST` that is in the inventory `windows` but I get this answer:

> [WARNING]: No hosts matched, nothing to do

How can I select a specific host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your parameters and their values in wrong order. It should be:

```
ansible MYHOST -i windows -m win_ping
```

The value of `-i` argument points to the inventory file, host pattern should be given directly.

You also don't need a comma, it was an old hack for defining the target without a need for inventory file.

Comment: Comma trick is to define "inline" inventories like: `ansible all -i '8.8.8.8,' -m ping`. In this case Ansible will not search for filename `8.8.8.8`, but use supplied string as inventory.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Thanks for reminding me. It got swapped out of my memory and only a tombstone remained.